# How to select only two decimal number without rounding in sql?

Tags: sql

My problem is I want to select two decimal number in `amount` column without rounding up. I have tried use `FORMAT` but rounding up my values

sql:

```
SELECT claim_type,amount
FROM detail
```

table `detail` :

```
id       claim_type             amount   
------   --------------------   -------              
1        FOOD REFRESHMENT       1.27000             
2        FOOD REFRESHMENT       2.35000
```

I want the output be like this when I select

```
claim_type             amount   
--------------------   -------              
FOOD REFRESHMENT       1.27            
FOOD REFRESHMENT       2.35
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is dependent on the dialect of SQL, but in general your examples won't be rounded by either `FORMAT` or `TRUNCATE` analogues. If you have a number such as `2.237` and try to format it to two numbers after the decimal point, it will be rounded up to `2.24` by those functions - but you can always cast it to a string datatype and then simply take a substring. In PostgreSQL:

```sql
% select substring(2.237::text, 1, 4);

 substring 
-----------
 2.23
(1 row)
```

Comment: I'm using MySQL. It works but this is the code that I use `SUBSTRING(amount, 1, 4) AS 'amount'` it gives me an error when I put the `text`. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the Cast function to get decimals values without rounding as below

```
SELECT Cast(Round(123.419,2,1) as decimal(18,2))
```

Comment: I tried using yours but it's giving me `Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'Round'` error. I'm not sure what that mean... but it's okay I have the answered already. thank you !